# Profile Completion e-mail to user in Drupal

Tags: 6, users

Hi in drupal(6) how to send reminder e-mail to the user whoever did not complete the profile information?

Is there any module available to do this? i think we can do using rules/trigger. but not exactly. I need similar to that what cron job do in php. Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), I actually have the below working for an Intranet site I manage.

**ON** - Choose your event, maybe "User has logged in"
**IF** - "Content Profile's field 'field_NAME' has value"
**DO** - "Send a mail to the user"

Replace the field_NAME with the field you would like to check, In the IF I just check for a NULL value on a required field.

```
return array( 0 => array('value' => ''), );
```